# Adding a navigation page state to individual blog and portfolio pages

Tags: php, css, navigation

I'm using a Woo Themes template (Simplicity) for a client's web site.

I'm using the portfolio page as the profile pages (Our Trainers).

Also have a blog category in the main nav.

How do I get the individual "portfolio" and blog pages to set the nav current page (.current_page_item)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in a menu you could use .current-menu-parent otherwise something like .current-post-parent or .current-page-parent

I hope this is what you mean. Otherwise a link to your current site would help alot.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the menu.
How/where do I affect that?

Example:
This page has the .current-menu-item class.
http://x5.centerlinebeta.net/our-trainers/

This one doesn't:
http://x5.centerlinebeta.net/our-trainers/joshua-hutchins/

Where do I affect it on the subpages?

Comment: Ah I see that this theme uses a page template for it's archive page. That's why there is no current-menu-parent class. What you can use is this: .single-portfolio .menu-item-265 { /* your active class css */ }

Comment: Just add that class comma separated to the css styles that are used for .current-menu-items?

Comment: Yes, if it is like this: .current-menu-items { /* some styles */ }, then make it like this: .single-portfolio .menu-item-265, .current-menu-items { /* some styles */ }